# Having trouble using addTextChangeListener & updating values?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I'm currently learning android in Kotlin, and I'm trying to create a tip calculator. I have two EditText views, one for the bill amount and tip amount. I also have two TextViews, one for the tip amount and one for the `total + tip`.

This is part of my code, where I am trying to have the EditText automatically update the TextViews upon user input.

```
billInput.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher) {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            totalAmt.text = billInput + tipInput
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
         
        }

    }
```

For now, I am trying to have the bill + tip amount be added and update the TextView. I got the error "Expecting a class body" next to the first line. Am I using `addTextChangedListener` incorrectly or is something wrong with my code? I know there are probably more efficient ways to do this, but I was assuming I could just use addTextChangedListener for both EditText views. So, to clear things up: I want to input my bill amount and tip amount, and automatically update "Tip amount:" and "Total:" .

Edit*** : Would it make sense to do the numeric calculations (tip and total amount) under onTextChanged? That way as the input is received, the calculations are processed and afterTextChanged is responsible for displaying the final results?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `EditText + EditText`, should add values instead

```
billInput.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher) {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            totalAmt.text = "${billInput.text.toString().toInt() + tipInput.text.toString().toInt()}"
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
         
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello my friend you can set `addTextChangedListener` for both EditTexts and put same code for both of them because one person cant simultaneously type in both EditTexts.
do the code like below.

**bill Input Edittext**

```
billInput!!.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
            //code after changed
            val bill = editable.toString().toInt()
            val tip = tipInput!!.text.toString().toInt()
            total.text = ((bill + tip).toString())
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
            //code before text change
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
            //code during change
        }
    })
```

**tip Input EditText**

```
tipInput!!.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
            //code after changed
            val bill = editable.toString().toInt()
            val tip = billInput!!.text.toString().toInt()
            total.text = ((bill + tip).toString())
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
            //code before text change
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
            //code during change
        }
    })
```